# Geom_line() in ggplot2 is not working as expected for a simple dataset. What is going on?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, geom

I'm trying to create a simple line plot in ggplot2 with a dataframe, but the results aren't appearing as expected.

Here is the code to reproduce the data:

```
tograph<-data.frame(PANEL=13:22,total=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))
```

And when I graph the results in ggplot2, it just creates a straight vertical line at PANEL=1 (SO won't let me post images at this time)

```
ggplot(data=tograph,aes(x=PANEL,y=total))+geom_line()
```

As a sanity check, I ran some example data I found on a different post to make sure it wasn't something unique to my installation of R and it worked fine

```
xValue <- 1:10
yValue <- cumsum(rnorm(10))
data <- data.frame(xValue,yValue)

# Plot
ggplot(data, aes(x=xValue, y=yValue)) +
  geom_line()
```

Similarly, graphing my intended data in  base R also works fine, but I'd prefer to set it up in ggplot2 for aesthetic reasons:

```
plot(tograph$PANEL,tograph$total,type="l")
```

Any help with fixing this is much appreciated.

Comment: Odd. For some reason this works `ggplot(data=tograph,aes(x=as.numeric(tograph$PANEL),y=total))+geom_line()`  I am not sure something to do with integer type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `PANEL` is a protected data.frame variable name in ggplot2. Use a different variable name, like `panel`.

(I suspect it has something to do with how ggplot2 processes the incoming data to prepare to plot it. e.g. from [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/63125db184b6e7d5516007574b5d15acbfd8f470/R/facet-.r):

> - `compute_layout`: Based on layer data compute a mapping between
>   #'   panels, axes, and potentially other parameters such as faceting variable
>   #'   level etc. This method must return a data.frame containing at least the
>   #'   columns `PANEL`, `SCALE_X`, and `SCALE_Y` each containing
>   #'   integer keys mapping a PANEL to which axes it should use. In addition the
>   #'   data.frame can contain whatever other information is necessary to assign
>   #'   observations to the correct panel as well as determining the position of
>   #'   the panel.

```
ggplot(data.frame(PANEL=13:22,
                  total=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)),
       aes(PANEL,total)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data.frame(panel=13:22,
                  total=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)),
       aes(panel,total)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the PANEL variable name you can use this code:

```
ggplot(data=tograph,aes(x=tograph$PANEL,y=tograph$total)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]